# Unicity of solution to a one parameter system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Assume that  $m,p,$ and $\rho$ are known constants. The functions $\theta(s)$ and $y(s)$ are smooth and defined on the interval $[0,1].$ They also satisfy the system:
\begin{equation}\label{ODE}\left\{ \begin{array}{lll}\theta'(s)(c-my(s))=p+\rho y(s)-m\cos\theta(s) \\ y'(s)=\sin \theta (s) \\ y(0)=0 \\ y(1)=0\\ \theta(0)=0 \\ \theta(1)=2\pi \end{array}\right.\end{equation}

Is the constant $c$ uniquely determined by $m,p,$ and $\rho?$

Answer (score 0):

As long as $y(s) \ne c/m$ you have a first-order system with a smooth right side, and
the solution with initial conditions $y(0)=0$, $\theta(0)=0$ is unique.  This unique solution may or may not satisfy the boundary conditions at $s = 1$.  It's not clear what happens if $y(s)$ hits $c/m$.

Comment: Thank you Robert! From your answer I realize that I need to rephrase my question.